# React Native - Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Following this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/126063/react-native-tutorial

I get the following errors at the Hello World stage:

```
2016-06-16 22:38:30.192 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined
2016-06-16 22:38:30.197 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.RCTExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined
2016-06-16 22:38:32.059 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module.
2016-06-16 22:38:32.060 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.RCTExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module.
```

The full code for `index.ios.js` is:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');

var styles = React.StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    color: 'black',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    fontSize: 30,
    margin: 80
  }
});

class PropertyFinderApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return React.createElement(React.Text, {style: styles.text}, "Hello World!");
  }
}

React.AppRegistry.registerComponent('PropertyFinder', function() { return PropertyFinderApp });
```

====
UPDATE

Later in the blog it mentions using some updated code. However, this also gives me errors. Specifically, the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
AppRegistry,
StyleSheet,
Text,
View,
NavigatorIOS
} from 'react-native';

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
text:
{
color: 'black',
backgroundColor: 'white',
fontSize: 30,
margin: 80
}
});

class PropertyFinderApp extends Component {
render() {
return "Hello World"
}
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('PropertyFinder', function()
{
return PropertyFinderApp;
});
```

and the errors:

```
2016-06-16 22:50:28.181 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Running application "PropertyFinder" with appParams: {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
2016-06-16 22:50:28.205 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] PropertyFinderApp.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
2016-06-16 22:50:28.209 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.RCTExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: PropertyFinderApp.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
```

Any suggestions what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The first version is not working because you should import `Component` from `'react'`, not from not `'react-native'`.

It should look like this

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactNative = require('react-native');
var {
  Image,
  AppRegistry
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} = ReactNative;

class PropertyFinderApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<View>
         <Text>
           Hello world
         </Text>
      </View>)       
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('PropertyFinder', () => PropertyFinderApp);
```

And the updated version is not working because your PropertyFinderApp Component is not returning an element, it's returning a String, which is wrong.

this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
     NavigatorIOS
} from 'react-native';

class PropertyFinderApp extends Component {
    render() {
      return "Hello World" // You should return an element, not a String
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('PropertyFinder',() => PropertyFinderApp; });
```

should be

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
     NavigatorIOS
} from 'react-native';

class PropertyFinderApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<View>
         <Text>
           Hello world
         </Text>
      </View>)       
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('PropertyFinder',() => PropertyFinderApp; });
```

Comment: I copied and pasted but the first gives me this error: [tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] undefined is not an object (evaluating 'React.AppRegistry.registerComponent')

Comment: I forgot to add AppRegistry from 'react-native'. Just import AppRegistry from 'react-native'. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I had my imports wrong and was looking for an answer for so long. This finally made me realise it was right in front of me.

Answer (score -1):

```
class PropertyFinderApp extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <View>
    <Text>
       Hello world
    </Text>
  </View>       
);
}
}
```